# Implementation of stored procedure with multiple input variables (table-valued-parameters)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

for a course I try to create a stored procedure with TSQL, which should create a service ticket in my DB for the various services that can be conducted on a vehicle. These services can include general_service(s), repair(s) and inspection(s) as well as some further information about costs. 
As a result if a serviceticket is successfully created after executing the procedure a serviceticket number should be returned.

Input parameters are:

```
VehicleId, ticketDate, customerId, serviceTypes (TVP), repairs (TVP), inspections (TVP)
```

Output parameter: ServiceTicket Number

Tables in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StandardService
(
    serviceId CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    leaseNo CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    serviceDate DATE NOT NULL,
    includesInspection CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    serviceName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    serviceDescription VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    currentPrice DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL CHECK(currentPrice BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99999.0) DEFAULT 0.0,

    FOREIGN KEY(includesInspection) 
        REFERENCES VehicleInspection(inspectionId)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(leaseNo) 
        REFERENCES VehicleLease(leaseNo)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.VehicleInspection
(
    inspectionId CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    inspectionName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    currentPrice DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    vehicleTypeId CHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

    FOREIGN KEY (vehicleTypeId) 
        REFERENCES VehicleType(vehicleTypeId)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
) 

CREATE TABLE dbo.VehicleRepair
(
    vehicleRepairId CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    vehiclePrvId CHAR(8),
    vehiclePurchId CHAR(8),
    ticketIssueNo CHAR(8),
    labourCost DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL CHECK(labourCost BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99999.0) DEFAULT 0.0,
    partCost DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL CHECK(partsCost BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99999.0) DEFAULT 0.0,

    PRIMARY KEY(vehicleRepairId),

    FOREIGN KEY(vehiclePrvId) 
        REFERENCES VehiclePrevLeased(vehicleId)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(vehiclePurchId) 
        REFERENCES VehiclePurchased(vehicleId)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(ticketIssueNo) 
        REFERENCES ServiceTicket(ticketIssueNo)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ServiceTicket
(
    ticketIssueNo CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    serviceDate DATE NOT NULL,
    vehicleId CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    customerId CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    inspectionId CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    serviceCost DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL CHECK(serviceCost BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99999.0) DEFAULT 0.0,
    inspectionCost DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL CHECK(inspectionCost BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99999.0) DEFAULT 0.0,
    repairCost DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL CHECK(repairCost BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99999.0) DEFAULT 0.0,
    GST DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    amountDue DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL CHECK(amountDue BETWEEN 0.0 AND 99999.0) DEFAULT 0.0,

    FOREIGN KEY(vehicleId) 
         REFERENCES Vehicle(vehicleId)
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(inspectionId) 
         REFERENCES VehicleInspection(inspectionId)
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(customerId) 
         REFERENCES Customer(customerId)
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
)
```

I have no previous experience in stored procedures and could not find a good example which relates to this more complex problem. I so far created three Tables for the TVP values.

Type for the three service types

```
CREATE TYPE ServiceType AS TABLE
(
    serviceId CHAR(8),
    PRIMARY KEY(serviceId) 
)

CREATE TYPE RepairType AS TABLE
(
    vehicleRepairId CHAR(8),
    PRIMARY KEY(vehicleRepairId) 
)

CREATE TYPE InspectionType AS TABLE
(
    inspectionId CHAR(8),
    PRIMARY KEY(inspectionId) 
)

-- Creating stored proc with input parameter to receive data 
-- for the table-valued parameter

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GenerateServiceTicket 
    @vehicleId CHAR(8),
    @serviceDate DATE,
    @customerId CHAR(8),
    @gst DECIMAL(8,4),
    @serviceType ServiceType READONLY,
    @repairType RepairType READONLY,
    @inspectionType InspectionType READONLY,
-- output parameter for stored procedure
    @ticketIssueNo CHAR(8) OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- How to continue in this case when multiple information needs to be retrieved first
```

from various tables, before being able to insert it into the

### ServiceTicket table to create a new Service Ticket

```
    INSERT INTO ServiceTicket 
    VALUES (@ticketIssueNo, @serviceDate, @vehicleId, @customerId, @inspectionId)

    SELECT *
    FROM @serviceType
    WHERE ...
END
```

How can I structure the procedure in this case if I need to query multiple tables in my database, collect all returned information and insert it into the ServiceTicket? Thanks very much for any hint/help.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Hi @marc_s thanks for that.

Comment: So you want to insert tickets for all these different types at once? I'm not sure I'm following the logic here.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to structure your proc using joins to collect data from different tables before inserting them into ServiceTicket. But in your insert statement, it looks like `@inspectionId` is the only data from your TVP `@InspectionType`. Other values correlate to `@vehicleId`, `@serviceDate` and `@customerId` from your SP input params. How are you planning to use the other two TVPs (`@ServiceType` and `@RepairType`)

Comment: The tables you listed, are they pre-defined or did you define them?

Comment: the tables were defined by me it said in the description input parameters should include:   serviceTypes (input) – A table-valued parameter (TVP) with the types of services that is conducted on the vehicle (if any) repairs (input) – A list of part numbers used for the repairs (if any) passed as a table-valued parameter (TVP)

Comment: If you could [edit] your question to include an example of the `exec usp_GenerateServiceTicket` (with all the parameters filled in, including the table valued parameters) and the data that should be inserted into the tables by that particular insert, that would make the question much easier to understand and solve. In fact, doing this exercise might help you solve it yourself, without the need to wait for an answer...

Comment: Structure it one step at a time.   There's not enough information here to help you beyond that.   This question is way too broad and unclear.